Lost signature control for my wallet
Im not a dev on SOL but I had my wallet compromised:

I saw Fabiano.sol thread on X and checked my wallet
Wallet was drained and now I dont have control to that wallet. I can't sign transactions and Meteora says "invalidAccountForFee" and other Dapps too I can't get anyhing signed. I still see my funds in those Dapps.
I tried to disconnect everything from my wallets, import my phantom wallet to solflare wallet, famousfoxes revoker and asked from Discord of Meteora and others.


Contacted the Phantom team about this and waiting an email reply


I havent found any way to get help on this matter. All I got from Meteora was "ask from Solana" and since there is no Solana help desk im asking from here.

Could someone look this transaction and give any advice?
https://solscan.io/tx/4ptLXHDCGSJGo93kBF2Vav8RGgUev1R9W4HwJLCmGRQpqkGjbeV9cPt6nxYwdWyUGdEa79FvFj7iTJjTTJYuxnAv
I hope I get this someway done and my balance to be liquid again...
